# Spring Security 3.1 intercept url not intercepting any urls

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

I have Spring Security 3.1 wired up and authenticating a user when the directly access the Login page, but no redirect is happening when the user is not authenticated.

Below are my configuration files that I have added or updated for Spring Security.  I have read most if not all of the posts on here regarding the intercept-url regarding the order. proper EL, access rights, etc and I am definitely missing something here.

I ended up trimming down the interecept-urls down to just one in my application for troubleshooting with a non-existent role, but still have not had any success.  @PreFilters are ignored as well, so I do think it is in the configuration somewhere but am not seeing it at all.

Environment is 
   Tomcat 7.0.22, Mojarra 2.1.21, Spring Security 3.1, Java7

No errors when starting the server.

Thanks for any help!

Regards,

Mike

**security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean:beans xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd   
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd"    
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:bean="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
<global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/templates/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/security/**" security="none"/>
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/error/access-denied.xhtml">
<intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_BLAH')"/>
<form-login default-target-url="/login.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml" />
<logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" logout-url="/logout.xhtml" invalidate-session="true"/>
<session-management>
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
</session-management>
</http>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<authentication-provider ref="consummateUserAuthenticationProvider">
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</bean:beans>
```

**services.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc     
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.comanche.authentication">
</context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>51200</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>/home/provider/temp-fu</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>Custom Page Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.comanche.web.filter.CustomPageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Custom Page Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableMissingResourceLibraryDetection</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/custom.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/faces/content/error/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/faces/content/error/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/classes/application-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/services.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow access to anonymous users you need to specify access="permitAll" on the intercept-url.

Other than that,

You might want to change your form-login element to something like this:

```
 <form-login login-page='/login.xhtml' default-target-url='/home/index.xhtml'
        always-use-default-target='true' />
```

as the default-target-url is the one that user is redirected after authentication or if you do not need it then remove it and also the always-use-default-target flag.

Also you are missing [RequestContextListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html) in your web.xml and these Spring listeners should be the first listeners.

And use

```
<access-denied-handler error-page="/error/access-denied.xhtml" />
```

as access-denied-page attribute is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am not looking for anonymous access since that is happening right now.  The problem that is happening is that nothing is getting redirected to the Login page when you are not authenticated.  When I changed the intercept-url to just pattern="/**" and removed all of the other http patterns it started redirecting to another page (although it is an invalid URL).

Comment: So you are trying to redirect to login page from a different page? Are you doing that using a hyperlink or are you doing forward/redirect from server code.

Comment: I am trying to get it to redirect to the login page which I was finally able to accomplish last night, but am also experiencing a lot of odd behavior (if I get the paths correct by adding in /faces/content/home/** the authentication principal no longer is valid) from simple changes to my security.xml file.  I think this now needs to move to a new question as it no longer applies to just intercept-url